# How to add a layout specific hook_preprocess_page to omega 4 using multiple layouts?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using omega 4 and I can't seem to be able to add a preprocess function to any of my pages using layouts

This is some tests I've made without any result.

1. Adding:

   web_contacto_rector_preprocess_page(&$variables)
   on

   [theme_name]/preprocess/page.preprocess.inc
2. Adding:

   web_contacto_rector_preprocess_page(&$variables)
   on

   [theme_name]/layouts/[layout_name]/[layout_name]-layout.preprocess.inc

Is there something I'm missing?